# C++ Template class/type to choose between max and min

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a templated class.

```
template <<typename T>>
myclass {
  // ...
}
```

I want `T` to be such that if I instantiate `myclass obj<T>` with a proper `T`,
the class should be able to choose between min or max of two numbers. ie myclass is instantiated with min or max as the case maybe.

I dont mind using std::less/std::more/std::max/std::min or any of the inbuilt functor objects.

However, I would prefer not to use enums in the constructor and then depending on the enum value, call min or max routines. I want the code to be a little cleaner.
Any ideas? Is it possible to do this at all in C++

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Could you elaborate on how your class would be used, preferably with a code sample?

Comment: What kind of numbers (``int``, ``float``, ``BigInteger``, ...) should it be able to use? Can you give an example of how you would like to use it?

Comment: Almost every piece of code you produced is syntactically wrong. I would recommend very strongly that you spend some time with a good textbook to learn the basics of C++ before trying something more advanced.

Comment: @all: Be nice to him, it's his first question here.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, your edit didn't make it a lot better. What's with the double angle brackets? `myclass obj<T>` doesn't make a lot of sense, either. And I *know* that you're extremely familiar with C++ syntax, so I wonder what the meaning of this could be.

Comment: @bitmask: I didn't invent the double brackets; they were already there. That may just be an attempt to deal with the formatting, granted, but that's the least of the issues: More importantly, there's no class key, and the object declaration syntax also doesn't work the way the OP uses it... *and* I still have no idea what's being asked. Some sort of generic min/max function? A trait class? A specialization?

Comment: It's funny- everyone else seems to be having trouble but this question seems easy to me.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a big deal. Consider the following:

```
template<typename T> class MyClass {
public:
    int foo(int a, int b) const {
        return T()(a, b);
    }
};
```

Now if `T` is a type whose `operator()` returns the maximum of it's two arguments, then you will return the maximum, and ditto for any other binary algorithm you wish to apply.

Comment: After reading the question again, I believe you understood his point better than I did.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, here we need to define the class T ourselves, in the ideal case do not want to do that. I would like to use existing inbuilt functions for it.

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]** I believe that I didn't fully get the point of your question and that @DeadMG's answer is in fact what you are looking for.

The template below allows you to instantiate a class which given T, MIN, MAX can provide some number X between MIN and MAX between T.

```
template<int T, int MIN, int MAX, int X = MIN + T/(MAX - MIN)>
class MyClass
{
  int foo() const
  {
    return X;
  }
};
```

Comment: The question is far to vague to determine what the actual problem could possibly be. So your interpretation seems as good as any.